# Heroku - Your account does not have access to my-new-app

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

Could anyone help me with pushing code to Heroku? It was working for me last time about 6 months ago but now after `git push heroku master` I get this:

```
remote: !       Your account  does not have access to my-new-app.
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/my-new-app.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Based on information I found in internet I tried genereting new keys and adding them to .ssh but it didn't help, removing all other keys also didn't help. This is on Windows 10 with new Heroku app.

Comment: Can you confirm if the current user have access to the same app

Comment: Yes, my user does have access to that app. I have created few different apps on heroku to troubleshoot this issue and result was always the same. As a workaround I used method of deploying from github which worked. But this is additional step which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing heroku login in the command line. After logging in from browser, you can return to CLI and git push should be working now.

Comment: I tried logging in from CLI/browser couple of times but result was the same - it didn't work complaining about permissions.